# Edit and debug HTML5 apps on VS code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

How can I launch and debug HTML5 apps in VS Code?
At debug settings is allowed only nodejs and mono projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Currently HTML (client side) JS debugging is not supported in VS Code. Please add your vote here: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/7768992-client-script-debugging</strike>

There is now an extension available to debug a target that supports the Chrome Debugging Protocol: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug